# Is there a way to get FullCalendar.io events to overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am looking for a way to make the below overlap rather than stack.

Example Image:

[image]

Essentially, just full width if overlap occurs.

I am using fullCalender version 5.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, this isn't possible via the fullCalendar API. You would have to re-write fullCalendar's internal rendering code to suit your purpose. It's possible that could be achieved by creating [custom views], but you would need to study the current fullCalendar source code to understand all the possibilities.

Alternatively, you can see if anyone has requested such a feature and vote for it, or submit your own feature request for the developers on the fullCalendar project to consider. Instructions are here: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features